# c++ Eigen: Why does summing up a chipped and sliced tensor give a different (wrong) result as opposed to when you use nested loops?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have the following example:

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
#include <Eigen/Core>

Eigen::Tensor<double, 5> test_tensor(3,3,2,1,1);
test_tensor.setValues({
  {{{{1.1}},{{1.1}}},{{{0}},{{0}}},{{{0}},{{0}}}},
  {{{{0}},  {{0}}},  {{{1}},{{1}}},{{{0}},{{0}}}},
  {{{{0}},  {{0}}},  {{{0}},{{0}}},{{{1}},{{1}}}}
});

//use chip and slice to compute the subtensor sum
template <typename TensorType>
auto tensor_sum(const TensorType& tensor) -> typename TensorType::Scalar {
  using T = typename TensorType::Scalar;
  T sum = 0; //provisory
  for (int i = 0; i < tensor.size(); ++i) {
    sum += tensor.data()[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> field_slice;
for (int l = 0; l < 3; ++l) {
  for (int m = 0; m < 3; ++m) {
    auto field_slice_ = test_tensor.chip(1, m).chip(0, l);
    field_slice = field_slice_.slice(
                    Eigen::array<Eigen::Index, 3>({0, 0, 0}),
                    Eigen::array<Eigen::Index, 3>({2, 1, 1}));
    std::cout << "sum slice " << l << " " << m << " " << tensor_sum(field_slice) << std::endl;
  }
}

// use nested loops to compute subtensor sum
double sum;
for (int l = 0; l < 3; ++l) {
  for (int m = 0; m < 3; ++m) {
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 1; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 1; ++k) {
          sum += test_tensor(l, m, i, j, k);
        }
      }
    }
    std::cout << "sum nested loops " << l << " " << m << " " << sum << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Which prints out

```
sum slice 0 0 0
sum slice 0 1 0
sum slice 0 2 1.1
sum slice 1 0 1
sum slice 1 1 1
sum slice 1 2 1.1
sum slice 2 0 1
sum slice 2 1 1
sum slice 2 2 1.1
sum nested loops 0 0 2.2
sum nested loops 0 1 0
sum nested loops 0 2 0
sum nested loops 1 0 0
sum nested loops 1 1 2
sum nested loops 1 2 0
sum nested loops 2 0 0
sum nested loops 2 1 0
sum nested loops 2 2 2
```

Why are the results different? I suspect that the `chip` or `slice` operation isn't working the way it's supposed to. Separating the two steps by first storing the chipped tensor and then creating the slice also didn't change the result. How can I compute the sum of my subtensor without using nested loops?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. When I copy paste your code id do not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/na7nvqshG and I do not want to fill blanks (omissions).

Comment: Ok turns out quick fix is possible: https://godbolt.org/z/a6cK5coY1

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for the reply, I will test my example on godbolt first next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing in wrong way here:

```cpp
auto field_slice_ = test_tensor.chip(1, m).chip(0, l);
```

Please read documentation:
[Eigen-unsupported: Eigen Tensors](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#title87)

> ### <Operation> chip(const Index offset, const Index dim)
>
> A chip is a special kind of slice. It is the subtensor at the given offset in the dimension dim. The returned tensor has one fewer dimension than the input tensor: the dimension dim is removed.
>
> For example, a matrix chip would be either a row or a column of the input matrix.

So basically you feeded arguments in wrong order.

[Fixed version](https://godbolt.org/z/hY59Tb5KG):

```cpp
auto field_slice_ = test_tensor.chip(m, 1).chip(l, 0);
```

or same result:

```cpp
auto field_slice_ = test_tensor.chip(m, 0).chip(l, 0);
```